# How get $index from first ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have next HTML code:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item)">
   <div ng-click="add($event, $index);"></div>

    <div ng-repeat="item in itemsTypeSubscribers">
       <input type="radio" ng-change="Change($index)" ng-model="type" name="type"/>Name
    </div>
</div>
```

How I can pass $index from first `ng-repeat` to method ng-`change="Change($index)"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$parent.$index`.

```
<input type="radio" ng-change="Change($parent.$index)" ng-model="type" name="type"/>Name
```

Comment: Thanks, I have not know about this